# stunnel "fingerprint does not match"

Tags: stunnel

I'm trying to run stunnel on a clean installation of Win7 and am encountering the following error:

```
FIPS_mode_set: 2D06906E: error:2D06906E:FIPS routines:FIPS_CHECK_INCORE_FINGERPRINT:fingerprint does not match
```

What does it mean?
How come that it appears on a clean install?

**UPDATE:**
I switched back from 4.49 to 4.46 and the problem disappeared. Perhaps it's a bug in a new stunnel release. I'll leave this post up so that anyone who encounters it will know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were right about the issue being a bug.  I encountered the same issue with 4.49.  However, the newly released 4.50 version appears to be fixed.